# How to select multiple values with SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in which cells can be as follows:

`user_group` can be `admin`, `allow`, `disallow`

`user_subscription` can be `all`, `penalty`, `autogoal`

I need to get the records that correspond to the following expression:

All `admin` and `allow` where `user_subscription` == ``` all`` or ```autogoal```

I tried to do it like this:

```sql
('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE (user_group="allow" OR user_group="admin" AND user_subscription="autogoal" OR user_subscription="all")')
```

But it does not work. I have 2 entries in the database:

1. `user_group`=`admin`, `user_subscription`=```all``
2. `user_group`=`allow`, `user_subscription`=```autogoal``

I always get only the second entry.

Comment: add parenthesis in your query: ```(c1 OR c2) AND (c3 OR c4)```

Comment: Tables don't have "cells", they have columns in rows. Thinking of a table as though it's a spreadsheet will cause nothing but pain. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use parentheses correctly, because the `AND` operator has higher precedence than the `OR` operator.
So your WHERE condition is equivalent to:

```
user_group="allow" 
OR 
(user_group="admin" AND user_subscription="autogoal") 
OR 
user_subscription="all"
```

Write the statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS 
WHERE 
  (user_group="allow" OR user_group="admin") 
  AND 
  (user_subscription="autogoal" OR user_subscription="all")
```

You can find more [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).
Or with the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS 
WHERE 
  user_group IN ("allow", "admin") 
  AND 
  user_subscription IN ("autogoal", "all")
```

Comment: Ty, this work in DB Browser for SQLite but not work in python. Python give me anyway first one result. U dont know why this is?

Comment: It should work in Python also, if you write it correctly and you query the same table. Check again.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some parenthesis in your WHERE clause

Try this :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM USERS
 WHERE (user_group="allow" OR user_group="admin")
   AND (user_subscription="autogoal" OR user_subscription="all")
```